# access arbitrary element of ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation without extra db query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a relation that is created, how could I access an element of the relation that matches some (very simple) condition without triggering an additional database query?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

joined = Foo.all.joins(:bars).select('foos.*, bars.baz')

a = joined.to_a # no additional query
b = joined.find_by_baz(1) # these will both generate additional queries
c = joined.find_by_baz(4) #   even though the data is already available
```

I may be missing something simple, but is there a way to access an arbitrary element of the association by an arbitrary value?

One possibly workaround I have thought of is to load the association into an array indexed by the value I'm interested in searching by. This seems more fragile than ideal though.

Comment: The data isn't `already available` until you attempt to examine the records.  So `a = joined.to_a` does the retrieval.  If you want to avoid subsequent db retrievals, use the records in the "a" array... `b = a.select(bas: 1).first`

Comment: that is a valid point about `already available` that i was aware of but didn't make explicit, thanks for mentioning. and using the array form with select seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to filter data, one is from the database, which is what you've done: `joined.find_by_baz(1)` the other is filtering on an array, which you can do by:

```
joined.to_a.select{|a| a.baz == 1}
```

This won't do an additional database call, but will use the [native select within the Enumarable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

Personally, I'd go with the database approach.

Comment: trouble with the database approach is that for my particular application it will wind up generating a hundred or so queries for this piece instead of 1. that may indicate i need to refactor how the data structures are set up and i may be able to accomplish it with a join as they already are, but it would be pretty ugly.

Comment: the to_a.select is accomplishing basically my workaround but in a more elegant way. it does solve my problem without an extra query though, so if nobody shows up soon with a `joined.find_by_baz_without_extra_query(1)` i'll accept it :)